# How to give class name to the text field in drupal

Tags: views, theming

I am new to drupal and I have a problem in drupal text-box.

Question : how to give a class for text box?

my html :

```
<input type="text" name="uname" class="uclass" id="uid">
```

i want the same in drupal

### **My code is** :

```
function my_module_my_form($form_state) {

// This is the first form element. It's a textfield with a label, "Name"

$form['name'] = array(

'#type'  => 'textfield',
                    '#title' => t('Enter Your Name'),
                    '#value' => t('Enter user name'),
                    '#name'  => 'uname',
                    '#id'    => 'uid',
                    '#class' => 'uclass',
                    '#maxlength' => 5
                   );
return $form;

}
```

Note: through inspect element , i find the class name is "form-text", but actually my class name is uclass, It is not taking, can one help me.

Answer (score 1):

Additional HTML attributes, such as 'class', can be added using the '#attributes' property.

```
function my_module_form_FORM_ID_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
   $form['name'] = array(
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => t('Enter Your Name'),
      '#weight' => -10,
      '#attributes' => array('class' => array('uclass')),
    );
 }
```

Please note that when you alter existing form elements (e.g. via hook_form_alter()), you probably want to add (attributes) to the existing array rather than writing over it.

Checkout [Form API](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7) of Drupal 7 to get more detail.